# Ambiguous integration

Tags: calculus, integration

I had come across the following question:

If we know $\int_0^9 f(u)du = 10$ and $\int_0^3 f(u)du = 14$ then what must the value of $\int_0^3 xf(x^2)dx$ be?

I reason that this value would be $30$ because if $\int_0^3 f(u)du = \int_0^3 f(x)dx$ then $\int_0^3 f(x^2) dx$ then evaluating for $x$ would be the same as evaluating from $0$ to $9$. Therefore $\int_0^3 f(x^2)dx = \int_0^9 f(u)du = 10$. Then all we do is multiply the value of $f(x^2)$ by 3 when we are evaluating the entire integral. Thus we end up with the answer $30$.

Would this reasoning be correct?

Comment: Not quite.  Try substituting $u=x^2,$  $du=2x \ dx$ in your integral.

Comment: You forgot to divide by $2$ when transforming with $du = 2xdx$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Begin with
$$\int_0^3 xf(x^2) dx,$$
and perform the $u$-substitution $u = x^2$ Then $du = 2x dx$, so that
$$\frac{1}{2} \int_0^3 f(x^2) 2xdx = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^9 f(u) du = 5.$$
Note that in your question, you claimed something different than the first equality. You claimed that
$$ \color{#AA0000}{\int_0^3 f(x^2)dx = \int_0^9 f(u)du},$$
which **is not true.** (I put it in red to emphasize that it's not a true statement).

Returning to the previous statement, this means that
$$\int_0^3 xf(x^2) dx = 5.$$

Comment: That absolutely makes sense. I very much appreciate your assistance.

Comment: @BarryCipra why, you're right. This is what happens when I type directly and don't write it down on paper, perhaps. I know I sometimes suffer from "blackboard blindness" when I'm teaching -- maybe I suffer from "MSE-answer blindness" too. Thank you

Comment: @mixedmath, been there, done that, more often than I care to admit.

Answer (score 4):

The change of variable $u=x^2$, $du=2xdx$ gives

$$\int_0^3 xf(x)\,dx={1\over2}\int_0^9f(u)\,du={10\over2}=5$$

The other piece of information, $\int_0^3f(u)\,du=14$, is irrelevant.  One wonders why it was mentioned.

Comment: I think it is mentioned to confuse you, because you shouldn't forget change the integral bounds.

Comment: @wythagoras, good point.

Answer (score 0):

No, you need to change variables, set $y=x^2$, so $dy = 2 x \, dx$:
$$ \int_0^{3} x f(x^2) \, dx = \frac{1}{2} \int_0^{9} f(y) \, dy, $$
and then you have the answer.